# Redirecting postgres service to new version

Tags: postgresql

I have a Centos 7 server running an old version of PostgreSQL that automatically starts when the server starts. To stop this postgres I use:

```
bash-4.4$ service postgresql stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop postgresql.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
```

To start the other newer PostgreSQL 14 I use from a user called postgres:

```
/usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_ctl -D /data/psql/data14 -l logfile start
```

What I need to do to make this one the default one at the starting of the server?

Thanks

Comment: Modify the environment variables so that these parameters point to the new version.

Comment: I think you can get better answer to this question at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also, you need to give us more details: what is your Linux distribution? What does your `postgresql.service` file look like?